# See if website user is from the same network ( intranet website )

Tags: authentication, authorization, intranet

I'm currently working on a intranet website. ( C# )

My client wants a certain page/certain content on a page to be available to people who are from their company but not to others. ( = people from sister companies can access the intranet website but shouldn't see everything )

My first suggestion was that users should be logged in, in once they're logged in that this would be easy to do.

BUT the client has stated that they do not want a login ( fearing that their employees wouldn't use it as it would require to much effort on their part )

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're in an Active Directory domain, you could use [Integrated Windows Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Windows_Authentication) to know the user's identity without them having to log on to the site. It uses the user's desktop log on session for authentication.

If that is not an option, you could whitelist IP-address ranges.